# How to construct a non-piecewise differentiable S curve with constant quick turning flat tails and a linear slope?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I need to find an example of a non-piecewise differentiable $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
     f(x)=C_1 &\text{ for } x<X_1,\\
     C_1 < f(x) < C_2 &\text{ for } X_1 < x < X_2,\\
     f(x)=C_2 &\text{ for } X_2<x.
\end{cases}
$$
For example, $\log(1+e^{Ax})$ is sort meets some characteristics in that

1. quickly flat lines around 0 for large A
2. has a linear slope for 0 < x < Xc

But it

1. does not flatline for Xc < x
2. I can't seem to control the slope of the linear section

So am looking for something different

Is there some other differentiable function that exhibits the above behavior?

Answer (score 2):

How about:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
C_1 & \text{if } x \le x_1 \\
\\
\dfrac{C_1-C_2}{2}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1) \right) + \dfrac{C_1+C_2}{2}  & \text{if } x_1 < x < x_2 \\
\\
C_2 & \text{if } x \ge x_2 \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I am looking for continuous differentiable function not a piece wise function. Like for example log(1+e^Ax) for a large A has a clean slope for x>0 and f(x)=0 for x<=0

Comment: @SarviShanmugham This piecewise function is continuous and differentiable for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$. Its derivative is given by:
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x \le x_1 \\ \\
\dfrac{\pi(C_2-C_1)}{2(x_2-x_1)}\sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1) \right) & \text{if } x_1 < x < x_2 \\ \\
0 & \text{if } x \ge x_2 \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I am looking for a non-piecewise function for machine learning. Keeps the math efficient without if/then/else. Similar to a sigmoidal, but I want a linear slope(not a curve), controlled by a constant S between -A < f(x) < +A. f(x) around +/-Xc should flatline quickly. For example log(1+e^Ax), is differentiable, flatlines to 0 for x<=0 "almost" instantly for large values of A,  is not piecewise, and has a linear slope for a section above 0 < x < Xc. But I can't seem to control the slope of the linear portion, nor flatline it on the top end for x > Xc.

Comment: @SarviShanmugham How about:
$$
f(x)=\dfrac{B}{1+e^{-Ax}}
$$
where increasing the value of the positive constant $A$ will **horizontally compress** the function, while increasing the value of the positive constant $B$ will **vertically expand** the function.

Comment: Well, this is basically a sigmoidal function. The main problem with this is that it does not flatline quickly, except for very large values of A, say A>100

Answer (score 1):

The following is a standard example in this regard: The function
$$\psi(t):=\cases{e^{-1/(1-t^2)}\quad&$(|t|<1)$\cr 0&$(|t|\geq1)$\cr}\ .$$
is defined piecewise, but is $C^\infty$ on all of ${\mathbb R}$. It  has a bump over the interval $[-1,1]$. Put $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x)\ dx=:C$. Then the antiderivative
$$\Psi(x):={1\over C}\int_{-\infty}^x \psi(t)\ dt $$
is $C^\infty$,  is $\equiv0$ for $x\leq-1$, and is  $\equiv1$ for $x\geq1$. Now adjust $\Psi$ to your data.

You cannot have a "single analytic expression" that does the desired job, because an analytic function that is constant on some interval has to be constant throughout.

Comment: wouldn't this be considered piece-wise? I want it to be continuous and NOT piecewise

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trying to mix various segments I came up with the following for my problem
f(x) = (1/(1+e^(100*(x-1))))*(1/(1+e^(-100*(x+1))))*x-(1/(1+e^(100*(x+1))))+(1/(1+e^(-100*(x-1))))

Which atleast seems to be in the right direction to meet all the requirements

1. Has a slope between -1 to +1.
2. Flatens quickly > 1 and < 1. How quickly can be controlled by changing the constant 100
3. is continuous and not pieceswise
4. is differentiable

I still haven't generalized it yet, but the general idea is to build it out of 3 segments

1. (1/(1+e^(100*(x-1))))*(1/(1+e^(-100*(x+1)))) multiplied by a slope and X for the sloping part
2. bottom flatline -(1/(1+e^(100*(x+1))))
3. top flat line (1/(1+e^(-100*(x-1))))